# how to prevent input focus for a single window in gnome-shell window manager?

Tags: window-manager, input, window, focus

I need a single window to be on top and never gain focus when any other window is closed.

In this case it is a gnome-terminal window w/o decorations, where I am running nethogs, it has a single text line in height. But when I close yakuake that gnome-terminal always get focus and messes my work flow (the browser, or netbeans or geany should receive focus but that ontop terminal always receive it).

I get the window id $nWID with xwininfo, and try all these commands but nothing works:

```
xprop -set WM_TAKE_FOCUS false -id $nWID
xprop -remove WM_TAKE_FOCUS -id $nWID
xprop -remove WM_PROTOCOLS -id $nWID
wmctrl -i -r $nWID -b add,skip_pager
wmctrl -i -r $nWID -b add,skip_taskbar
xprop -id $nWID -format WM_HINTS 32cbcxxiixx -set WM_HINTS 3,False,1,0x0,0x0,0,0,0x0,0x0
```

to remove decorations, I use this:
https://gist.github.com/muktupavels/d03bb14ea6042b779df89b4c87df975d
could the only way to do that, may be... to tweak the above code to add such functionality?

related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56559726/5648245

Comment: this worked here: update: check this comment, it has the code that works here! https://gist.github.com/muktupavels/d03bb14ea6042b779df89b4c87df975d#gistcomment-3331569

Answer (score 0):

original code at:
https://gist.github.com/muktupavels/d03bb14ea6042b779df89b4c87df975d#gistcomment-3331569

working fork:
https://gist.github.com/AquariusPower/113f4559a4ac8ccb0225a89b9c74c0ea

compile instructions are inside it at top comment.